# using jquery localstorage to reload page and display a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Working on the section, i had used localstorage to load the page, but i am bit confused as i want to pass a custom message to display

My usage till now:

```
success: function(data) {
                if ($.trim(data) == 'Complete') {
                    localStorage.setItem("Success","Thanks this is complete") 
                    location.href = 'index';
}
```

and at the top i have this: after document ready

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Success"))
{
    $(".msg").html(data); -  data i want the message to be appearing which i defined in the localStorage.setItem("Success","Thanks this is complete")
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

Comment: `$(".msg").html(localStorage.Success)`

Comment: plus 1 for you too, i can't update it somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the get method from local storage should do the trick
localStorage.getItem("Success")

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Success"))
{
    $(".msg").html(localStorage.getItem("Success") ); 
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

LocalStorage is window property and not jquery function....